# How to count Elements in a MongoDb Gridfs with the C# Driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I want to know how I can count all Elements of a GridFSBucket wiht the MongoDB C# Driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GriFSBucket is always over [bucketname].files and [bucketname].chunks with bucketname = fs or other name if you specify

```
var bucket = new MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.GridFSBucket(db, new MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.GridFSBucketOptions() { BucketName = "otherName" });
```

So to count the number the number of documents in a collection use

```
var db = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("flow");
var count = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("fs.files").Find(_ => true).CountDocuments();
```

> _ => true

means all element of the collection.